# importing and using BrowserModule (indirectly) causes error Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule

Tags: angular8, metronic

I am on a project which requires me to use Umbraco for common functionality such as user management and managing texts for e-mails (backoffice) and metronic angular version for the rest of the functionality. The angular app is getting all its data through web API.

To get these 2 working together, I created an ASP.NET MVC5 project, installed Umbraco and make it work that a view (cshtml file) could load an CLI generated angular app, without metronic yet and got this working.

Next I copied the metronic project in my solution folder and start stripping and moving it, as it comes with way too much overhead and demo code, demo data, demo images etc. When I got it a bit of working in the way I wanted to and it runs fine with `ng serve -o` I builded my code with `ng build` and included the output of my dist in my MVC project.

Unfortunately, this isn't working. I get this error:

> I got the error Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)

As I found many solutions and tried some of them like installing and importing core-js, none seems to fix the issue. So I build the "out of the box and untouched" metronic demo project and used that instead and that was working. So I figure I stripped the demo project a bit too much.

The next step I took, was to comment as much code as possible out in my angular project so it didn't use any of the metronic code nor any of my code. I ended up with this code, which doesn't give any errors when I run it with `ng serve -o` but does give errors when opening the output of `ng build` in the view.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; //, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; //APP_INITIALIZER,
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',  //'body[kt-root]',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Yet this code still generates the error:

> I got the error Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?)

When I comment the import of BrowserModule and remove it from the imports, I get a different error:

> In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js

But this error makes a bit sense, probably due to or during the building of the code, Zone.js is not found.

My questions for this problem are:
- Is browsermodule causeing this error?
- Or is something else that is used by the browsermodule causing this error? 
- What is the difference between `ng serve` and `ng build` that causes this error when I run the built version of the code?

If any more information is needed, please let it know and I will do my best to provide it, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was missing a script include. I needed to include 2 polyfills, one with and one without -es5 in the file name.